# Pandas show column number

Tags: python, pandas

is there any way to get pandas to show the column number and the column name at the same time? I'm dealing with a dataset with >30 columns, all of very long column names and some with little variation with each other. Its an absolute chore to type out the names when writing out the code. (i would still need to see the column names to know which columns to select)

thanks.

Comment: sorry, new to this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible solution is create `MultiIndex` and then select columns by [`DataFrame.xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],
                   'B':[4,5,6],
                   'C':[7,8,9],
                   'D':[1,3,5],
                   'E':[5,3,6],
                   'F':[7,4,3]})

print (df)
   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  1  4  7  1  5  7
1  2  5  8  3  3  4
2  3  6  9  5  6  3

df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([pd.RangeIndex(len(df.columns)), df.columns])
print (df)
   0  1  2  3  4  5
   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  1  4  7  1  5  7
1  2  5  8  3  3  4
2  3  6  9  5  6  3

print (df.xs(2, level=0, axis=1))
   C
0  7
1  8
2  9
```

Comment: You can perform the same with `df[2]`